# How to use stimulsoft in .NET6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, stimulsoft

I want to use stimulsoft in a project written in **ASP.NET MVC .Net6**.
StimulSoft version is 2022.1.1 and I installed NuGet

> Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore

in my project.

Controller:

```
    ...
    public IActionResult PrintPage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult GetReport()
    {
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "wwwroot/Reports/sample1.mrt"));
        var list = _unitOfWork.RefereeTypeRepos.GetAll(); //Get information for print.
        report.RegData("DT", list);
        return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, report);
    }

    public IActionResult ViewerEvent()
    {
        return StiNetCoreViewer.ViewerEventResult(this);
    }
```

PrintPage.cshtml:

```
    @using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc
    @using Stimulsoft.Report.Web
    @Html.StiNetCoreViewer(new StiNetCoreViewerOptions()
    {
        Actions =
        {
            GetReport = "GetReport",
            ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
        }
    })
```

When the page loads, I get this **Error**:
[image]

I don't know what I should do, and which version or NuGet is proper for .Net6?
I appreciate somebody answers.

Comment: What is wrong with my question that somebody votes me down?

Comment: I searched a lot and tried many different codes. Instead of 'report.load' I used 'report.loadducument' the error is gone, but shows just an empty page, using the trial version of Stimulsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
public IActionResult GetReport()
    {
        var person = new { Name = "samplename", Family = "samplefamily" };
        StiReport report = new StiReport();

        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        report.Load(path + "\\Reports\\Ticket.mrt");

        var service = new Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportService();

        report.RegData("PersonDetail", person);
        
        report.Render(false);

        StiPdfExportSettings st = new StiPdfExportSettings();
        st.ImageQuality = 1f;
        st.EmbeddedFonts = true;
        st.ImageResolution = 300;
        st.ImageFormat = StiImageFormat.Color;
        st.AllowEditable = StiPdfAllowEditable.No;

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        // Export PDF using MemoryStream.
        service.ExportTo(report, stream, st);

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=card.pdf");
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
    }
```

It creates a pdf file and I use Nuget: *stimulsoft.reports.engine.netcore*

and there is no need for `ViewerEvent()` and `PrintPage.cshtml`

Comment: thanks, I have solved my problem by exporting a new pdf file, but is there any way to show in the viewer and then save it?